# Scope of variables in C and making functions talk to each other

Tags: c

At the moment I'm currently doing a university project where we are coding Pong the game from scratch to work on a microcontroller that has an LCD attached.

I'm struggling on a couple of different aspects as the C language that we're using is quite new to me.

To give you a brief overview of my situation at the moment, we are being told to code the entire game inside a single class that takes the form below;

```
int main()
{
//initalisation code for lcd, buttons, etc

    while(true)
    {
        //game code that is run continuously
    }

}
```

Everything inside the while(true) loop will be run continuously in order to make the game work, this will consist of code that renders objects, checks for collisions, keeps track of score etc. One of my major problems at the moment is the fact that we have been told to keep global variables to an absolute minimum. But I really don't know how to make all the different functions work together with each other.

For example, if I have a function called initGame() within main() that initialises int lives = 5, this means that the scope of lives is only within initGame(), so how do I get the functions within the while(true) loop to know that lives has already been declared so I can adjust lives when the user loses a life? Am I supposed to use get functions like in Java?

This is the main problem I'm having, as I really don't understand how these functions are supposed to work together. If I were able to use global variables I could do it, but without them I really have no idea.

Comment: "Everything inside a class as seen below" that is not a class and C does not have classes. That is the main function. initGame can either return an integer or pass by reference. For instance int initGame() { return 5; } or void initGame(int& lives) {lives = 5; } inside your main above while(true) you can do int lives; and when you need to call the function just do lives = initGame();

Comment: my friend there no classes in c :

Comment: you can pass values out and in function by using POINTERS !!!!!!!

Comment: By "within a single class", do you mean within the `main` function?  Or just all in the same source file?

Comment: So you're saying to declare lives inside the while(true) loop, and then have a separate function outside of main() that is used to set the values of lives? Does a variable count as a global variable if it is declared inside main()?

Comment: Inside the same souce file John Bode

Comment: I see that you have previous Java experience. Throw all of those `class` ideas out because C is about memory management comparing to Java you have syntactical auto-garbage collected classes.

Comment: @Ajek don't declare anything in the while loop, it will continuously re-declare/intialize them based off what you are doing. Unless you want that. Just declare what you need above your while loop, and make functions outside of main and call them inside your while loop whenever you need. I really am not sure what you need but lets say you were doing something that takes damage. In your while loop you would have like if(damaged_taken_from_Monster) { lives --; } if(lives == 0) { cout << "GAME OVER" << endl; } if(user_wants_to_Play_Again) { initGame(); }, just a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `lives` to be local to `initGame`. Have this value initialised at the beginning of `main`:

```
<return_type> initGame(int *lives /* more args */) {
    *lives = 5;
    // other code
}

int main() {
    int lives = 0;

    initGame(&lives);
}
```

By the way, you can't have "a function called `initGame()` within `main()`" as this is non-standard in C, these functions should be defined separately, although `initGame` can be *declared* inside `main`, but doing this doesn't make much sense here.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct GameState
{
       int lives;
  /* More stuff*/
};

InitGame( struct GameState*)
...
```

You can create structures and use them as parameters

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of structures? Typedef enum and struct are two things I really don't understand in C. Why would I pass GameState as a parameter?

Comment: You are not passing GameState as a parameter. Look closely and you can see that it is passing a *pointer* to the `struct GameState`.

Answer (score 0):

Some variables could be static inside you functions. This will help you to store some data during function call and protect it against using somewhere else in you code.

One more, you can hide global variables inside translation units by making them static.

Try to think out the structure of your project, function calls and argument passing.

Answer (score 0):

If `int lives;`  is used by any of the functions run from within the main loop, you'd declare it in the main loop and then pass the address of lives (&lives) to the functions that need to write to it.

Instead of:

```
int lives = 9;
void take_life(){
   live--;
}
int main()
{
   while(1){ 
     //...
     take_life();
     //...
   }
}
```

you'd do:

```
void take_life(int *lives) 
{ 
    *lives -= 1; 
}
int main()
{
    int lives = 9;
    while(1){
         //...
         take_life(&lives);
         //...
    }
}
```

You might want to group such variables into a state struct so you'd only have to pass one pointer.

Comment: C is so confusing, why do I have to use a struct to pass the variables?

Comment: You don't. Only if you more such variables and you only want to pass on pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, if I have a function called initGame() within main() that initialises int lives = 5, this means that the scope of lives is only within initGame(), so how do I get the functions within the while(true) loop to know that lives has already been declared so I can adjust lives when the user loses a life? Am I supposed to use get functions like in Java?

The objects representing the game state will have to be defined within `main`, and you will pass those objects as arguments to any functions that need to use or update them.  Let's start by assuming `lives` is the only thing you need to keep track of:

```
void initGame( int *lp )
{
  *lp = 5;
}

int main( void )
{
  int lives;
  ...
  initGame( &lives );
  ...
}
```

We define the variable `lives` within `main`.  We pass a *pointer* to this variable to `initGame`.  `initGame` updates `lives` via the pointer `lp`.  C passes all function parameters *by value*, so the formal parameter in the function definition is a *different object* in memory than the actual parameter in the function call.  If we had written this as

```
void initGame( int lives )
{
  lives = 5;
}
```

this would update the value of the formal parameter, but would have no effect on the *actual* parameter (the variable `lives` in `main`).  So, any function that needs to write to a parameter needs to receive a *pointer* to that parameter:

```
void foo( T *p )
{
  *p = new_value; // writes to the object that p points to
}

void bar( void )
{
  T var;
  foo( &var ); // writes a new value to var
}
```

Depending on how much state you need to keep track of, it may make sense to group individual items together into `struct` types:

```
struct playerState {
  int lives;
  int score;
  // additional player attributes here
};

struct gameState {
  int paddleSize;
  int ballSpeed; 
  // additional game attributes here
};
```

Then within `main` you create instances of these objects:

```
int main( void )
{
  struct playerState players[2]; // assuming 2 players
  struct gameState game;

  initGame( players, &game );
  ...
}
```

Then `initGame` would look something like

```
void initGame( struct playerState *players, struct gameState *game )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
  {
    players[i].lives = 5;
    players[i].score = 0;
    ...
  }

  game->paddleSize = 5;
  game->ballSpeed = 1;
  ...
}
```

This is only a rough example - without knowing the details of your requirements or design, I can't give you much more than this.  I know you're going to have
questions about pointers, the `.` vs. `->` operators, arrays, etc.  All I can say is find a good C reference and study it.  [Harbison & Steele](http://careferencemanual.com) has been my go-to reference since the late '80s.